# ManagedObject attributes are nil after second reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, executefetchrequest

I have value:

```
private var journeysArray : [JourneyInformation]!
```

In `viewWillAppear` I load data from Core Data:

```
        let moc = DataController().managedObjectContext
        let reqest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "JourneyInformation")
do {
        journeysArray = try moc.executeFetchRequest(reqest) as! [JourneyInformation]
        journeysTableView.reloadData()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Core data error \(error)")
    }
```

In first reload data all works well, and I can get all needed information, but after second reload:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        tableView.reloadData()
```

Attributes in the `JourneyInformation` object are nil. `journeysArray` show that it contain 4 objects as before.
How get objects and works with them without losses?

Comment: where you are declaring journeysArray

Comment: @RohitKP it is class property
class SavedJourneysScreen: UIViewController {
    private var journeysArray : [JourneyInformation]!
    ...

Comment: Have you tried to remove the private property

Comment: Do you mean you log them and they show as faults or the data is actually nil on screen?